# How come my JSF code is getting a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"?

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.1

I am getting a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` and I am not sure how to avoid it.   I am writing out to what I thought was basically a socket buffer.  I think it is `javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter`.

However, when I attempt to write very large HTML file, ~700,000 lines, I get a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.  I confused why the framework doesn't just flush to socket.  (Marsha, Marsha, Marsha)  Kidding aside, can I make it flush to socket rather just growing the buffer.

I am using JSF 1.1.

Note, I did try adding this web.xml:

```xml
<context-param>  
    <param-name>facelets.BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>  
    <param-value>500000</param-value>  
</context-param>
```

It did not seem to change anything.

Here is my code sample:

```jsp
<html>
    <f:view>
        <head>
            <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body id="page_body"
            <h:form id="form">
                <%
                    String s;
                    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                        s = data.get(i);
                        out.println(s);
                        //flush after on every thousandths row.
                        //if(i%1000==1)
                        //         out.flush();
                    }  // for loop
                %>
            </h:form>
        </body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Here is the exception I get:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:322)
    com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:130)
    test.CustomLocaleRemapViewHandler.renderView(CustomLocaleRemapViewHandler.java:94)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:87)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:200)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
    test.CustomFilter.doFilter(CustomFilter.java:46)
    test.CustomFilter2.doFilter(CustomFilter2.java:81)
    org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:144)


root cause 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:746)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    org.apache.jsp.test2_jsp._jspService(test2_jsp.java:122)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:322)
    com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:130)
    test.CustomLocaleRemapViewHandler.renderView(CustomLocaleRemapViewHandler.java:94)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:87)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:200)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
    test.CustomFilter.doFilter(CustomFilter.java:46)
    test.CustomFilter2.doFilter(CustomFilter2.java:81)
    org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:144)


root cause 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
    org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:745)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:746)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    org.apache.jsp.test2_jsp._jspService(test2_jsp.java:122)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:322)
    com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:130)
    test.CustomLocaleRemapViewHandler.renderView(CustomLocaleRemapViewHandler.java:94)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:87)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:200)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
    test.CustomFilter.doFilter(CustomFilter.java:46)
    test.CustomFilter2.doFilter(CustomFilter2.java:81)
    org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:144)


root cause 

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
    sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(Unknown Source)
    sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)
    java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    test.CustomWrapper$CustomPrintWriter.write(CustomWrapper.java:82)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:119)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:336)
    java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.write(HtmlResponseWriter.java:519)
    com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.ViewTag.doAfterBody(ViewTag.java:196)
    org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:725)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

BTW, BalusC, if your out there please help. No pressure, lol. You answer about half the JSF questions.

Grae

Comment: Your question implies that smaller files work without problems. Is that correct?

Comment: @koloossus Yes, it works fine.  It looks like BodyContentImpl is writing to a char[] cp, rather than writing to the socket.

Comment: Nothing is going to arbitrarily write to a different output; it's a simple case of the amount of data overwhelming the heap. Tweak your heap size settings to sort this out

Comment: @kolossus If you look at the code for BodyContentImpl, pushBody does change the "out" from the response writer to char buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using -Xmx to increase heap size. 
For apache tomcat use i.e. export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx1024M"